# Multi level routing in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement multiple routing inside nested routing using **ui-router** here is my routing config:

```
     $stateProvider
     .state('login', {
         url: '/',
         templateUrl: './app/login/login.html',
         controller: 'loginController as lc'
     })
     .state('orgProfile', {
         url: '/orgProfile',//1st level of routing
         templateUrl: 'app/companyProfile/companyProfile.html',//this page is displayed in ui-view of the index page
         controller: 'orgController as oc'

     })
     .state('orgProfile.employee', {//second level of routing
         url: '/employee',
         views: {
             'nestedViews': {**//name of the ui-view in companyProfile.html**
                 templateUrl: 'app/employee/employee.html',// up to here routing is fine.
                 controller: 'employeeController as em'
             }
         }
     })

 .state('orgProfile.employee.empDetails', {
     url: '/jfp',         
     views: {
         'nestedViews': { 
             templateUrl: 'app/employee/employeeDetail.html',
             controller: 'employeeDetailController as edm'
         }
     }
 })
```

My routing is fine up to employee.html page, i.e I have completed nested routing. Now I just want to change the ui-view which is currently showing the details of employees.
This is where I am calling ui-sref

```
<md-content layout-padding layout-wrap>
<md-list>
<md-list-item ng-repeat="emp in em.empDetails">    
<md-button ui-sref="orgProfile.employee.empDetails" >{{emp.username}}  </md-button>
</md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Any one please explain me how to perform such routing. Any suggestions and comments are highly appreciated.

[image: my logic here:-"after second level of routing when I click inside that level I want to reverse back or clear current routing and populate it with new routes inside the same routes "]

Comment: Hi, to answer your question I need to see the content of "app/companyProfile/companyProfile.html' to see how ui-views are organized.

Comment: the full page is too long here it is andrea, 
</md-list-item>
           <md-list-item>
           <md-button ui-sref="orgProfile.employee" ui-sref-active="active">
           <p>View Employee</p>
           </md-button>
        </md-list-item>